# Is there a "broadcast" method in HTML/CSS/Javascript?

Tags: html

So in the site scratch.mit.edu, there is a way so that once a block of code is finished, it can broadcast a statement. Its a really useful tool and I was wondering if there is something like/similar to that in coding!

Does anyone know if there is or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "broadcast", exactly?

Comment: Broadcast means it can broadcast "x" and then in other sprites you can put a "when i receive x" block

Comment: yes you can broadcast.  look into socket.io library

Comment: @DCR do you have a link to it?

Comment: yes of course...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [creating and triggering custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Example:

```
//create a new custom Event object called build
const event = new Event('build');

// create an event listener (attached to the global window object)
//This is like a Scratch receiver hat block. The first parameter, 'build', is the 
//name of the broadcast. The second parameter, the function, is your code 
//that reacts to the broadcast.
window.addEventListener('build', function (e) { /* your code here */ });

//This line of code "sends" the broadcast. 
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Have fun learning JavaScript!